# How to set default web page while opening new tab in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am using Microsoft Edge, *Version 88.0.705.53 (Official build) (64-bit)*. When I opening a new tab the following content is displayed:

[image]

But now I want to specify my default page when opening a new tab (like https://www.google.com/ ).

Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: I have confirmed that the suggested add-on is applicable to Microsoft Edge.  Chrome and Edge are both Chromium based browsers, which means an answer that is applicable to Edge, but submitted answering a question about Chrome can still be used as a duplicate (IMO).

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for prompt reply. Unfortunately in our case, this solution cannot be used, because of in **a new license agreement** is involved in this case. It would be nice to find a way to configure the new version. Some configuration settings have changed in the new version. It worked for us in the old version.

Comment: It cannot be done without an add-on.

Comment: Kindly check if this article from Microsoft can help you: [Change your browser home page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/change-your-browser-home-page-a531e1b8-ed54-d057-0262-cc5983a065c6)

Comment: @Sunny: Thanks for your remark. This solution was checked. This option is related to the **Show home** button. It might be used as workaround, but required to press the **Show Home** button. We will look at ability to configure through Microsoft Edge policy settings.